# Grails: Removing Unwanted Brackets when Displaying Variable

Tags: grails

I have a .gsp page where a student can select a course that they are in. That selection is then stored in an array list. I have another .gsp page that shows student details and within those details it shows which course they selected from the other page. However, when it displays the course it displays like this: "[courseName]", but I would like it to display without the brackets: "courseName".

This is my code for displaying the selection:

```
<g:if test="${studentDetails?.course}"> 
    <li class="fieldcontain"> 
        <span id="course-label" class="property-label"> 
        <g:message code="student.course.label" default="Course(s)" /></span> 
        <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="course-label"> 
        <g:set var="course" value="${studentDetails?.course.courseName}" /> 
        <g:message message="${course}" /></span>
    </li> 
</g:if>
```

So far I've tried displaying the variable with g:fieldValue, g:message, and just the variable itself without a tag. All methods display with the brackets. Any suggestions on how to remove the brackets are appreciated. If any other code is needed I can provide it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `studentDetails?.course.courseName` contains a `List` of courses and your want to display all of them, you need to convert it to a `String`. But default implementation of `List.toString()` uses brackets. Your could use `.join(',')` instead.

Like:

```
<g:if test="${studentDetails?.course}"> 
    <li class="fieldcontain"> 
        <span id="course-label" class="property-label"> 
        <g:message code="student.course.label" default="Course(s)" /></span> 

        <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="course-label">
        ${studentDetails.course.courseName.join(', ')}
        </span>
    </li> 
</g:if>
```

Also I suggest to add `.encodeAsHTML()` if you got this data (course name) from a user, to escape any HTML content inside variables (avoid XSS, etc). Like:

```
${studentDetails.course.courseName.join(', ').encodeAsHTML()}
```

Comment: ${studentDetails.course.courseName.join()} worked for me. Thanks!